# how to plot the loss from the log file

Tags: matplotlib

The below mentioned are the loss values generated in the file 'log'(the iterations are actually more than this what I listed below). Attached the screenshot of the contents of the log file for ref. How to plot the Iteration (x-axis) vs Loss (y-axis) from these contents in the 'log' file ?

```
0:  combined_hm_loss: 0.17613089
1:  combined_hm_loss: 0.20243575
2:  combined_hm_loss: 0.07203530
3:  combined_hm_loss: 0.03444689
4:  combined_hm_loss: 0.02623464
5:  combined_hm_loss: 0.02061908
6:  combined_hm_loss: 0.01562270
7:  combined_hm_loss: 0.01253260
8:  combined_hm_loss: 0.01102418
9:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00958306
10:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00824807
11:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00694697
12:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00640630
13:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00593691
14:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00521284
15:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00445185
16:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00408901
17:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00377806
18:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00314004
19:  combined_hm_loss: 0.00287649
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQIPl.png)

Comment: What the results do you have so far? Please, show your work. Did you try to check examples in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html) to this library? First of all you need to split each of your line to two values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
index combined_hm_loss
0:   0.17613089
1:   0.20243575
2:   0.07203530
3:   0.03444689
4:   0.02623464
5:   0.02061908
6:   0.01562270
7:   0.01253260
8:   0.01102418
9:   0.00958306
10:   0.00824807
11:   0.00694697
12:   0.00640630
13:   0.00593691
14:   0.00521284
15:   0.00445185
16:   0.00408901
17:   0.00377806
18:   0.00314004
19:   0.00287649
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
ax = df.plot.area(y='combined_hm_loss')
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks r-beginners. Appreciate your answer.